# k-regular graph , minimum edges deduction set

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have a $k$-regular-graph where $k $ is an even number. If we call $ S $ as the minimum-edges-deduction-set (minimum amount of edges we have to delete from G to make it incoherent) and how can we prove that $|S| $ is an even number? In other words, how can we prove that $S $ contains an even number of edges?

Comment: Do you mean k-_regular_ -- i.e. every vertex has the same degree k?

Comment: yes thats what i mean. and $|S| = \lambda(G)$ and we have to prove that if k is even, then |S| is also and even number

Comment: Answer edited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider expanding on the proof that a $k$-regular graph, for even $k$, cannot have a bridge (an edge cut of odd order). That's done by contradiction. Suppose such a bridge $uv$ exists, and consider the two component graphs of $G-uv$. Now all vertices of each component have even degree except for one ($u$ or $v$). This is a contradiction by the Handshaking Lemma.

What goes wrong below if you remove the odd number of edges in S? How are the vertex degrees in each component affected (shown in red)? It fails on the Handshaking Lemma, or more generally, on the degree sum formula. 
[image]

Comment: i am really really sorry, I did not mean k-connected... problem is about k-normal graphs... sorry... i will edit it asap

Comment: can you please give me an answer now?

Comment: i am a little confuced with your answer... can you please explain your answer a little bit more?

Comment: You want to show that the order of $S$ cannot be odd. I took the special case where $|S| = 1$ to show what goes wrong. Your strategy for solving the general case will also entail showing how it breaks the Handshaking Lemma. (That is, the component graphs cannot have an odd number of odd vertices.)

Comment: and how do we show that component graphs cannot have an odd number of odd vertices? or atleast that one component graph will have odd number of odd vertices? I am trying some examples but since we are talking about a minimum edge cut this makes things more difficult since for a k-regular graph, i dont know whats the minimum amount of edges we have to remove to make it disconnected

Comment: and since we are talking about minimum edge cut,i think that they can only be 2 component graphs out of G-S, or S would not be minimum cut set

Comment: Yes, there will only be two component graphs. Also, you don't care how many exact edges are in the edge cut, you only need to show that it can't be an odd number. Remember that in any graph, the sum of degrees of all vertices is always even. If you remove an odd number of edges to produce two component graphs, you're decreasing that sum in each component by an odd number. All the other vertices have even (k) degree. What's that tell you?

Comment: So let me get this straight. If for example we remove 5 edges from a graph and create 2 components,then each component will have its sum decreased by 5.And if at the start the sum was even, now it will be odd? So we have a contradiction by Handshaking Lemma?

Comment: Yes, basically, but you have to use the information that G is k-regular and that the edges you're removing are an edge cut.

Comment: I can use the edge cut information to say that they can only be 2 components, and i can also say that since k is even,decreasing degree by 1 will give us odd degree, but i cant see how we can use the fact that G is k-regular

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49732/discussion-between-bvy-and-aggelos-sfakianos).